# is obfuscated C# or Java easier to decompile than C because of stack machine - register machine difference? or are there other reasons?

Tags: clr, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I have seen it said that decompiling of obfuscated C# and Java is simplified by presence of calls to framework api, like to String. But, this doesn't quite make sense to me because shouldn't a C program also have obvious calls to some standard libraries, which would be equivalent of C# apis?

I have also seen it said that somehow the distinction between register machine (the hardware that will run assembly from C) and stack machine (virtual machine that will run bytecode) is important for complexity of decompilation.

So is stack/register machine issue the main one here? Let's say if CLR virtual machine were reimplemented as register machine, would C# bytecode all of a sudden become just as hard to decompile as is C executable? Or are there some other major complexity differences that will not go away on such platform overhaul?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between stack and register machines, it is relatively easy to deconstruct the expression trees from both representations.

.NET and JVM are so easy to decompile mainly because of the metadata: types and methods names, etc.

With a stripped native executable you'll have all the fun: no meaningful names for the functions, no explicit data types, loads of the inlined (and then severely mutilated by the further optimisation) code, unrolled loops, irreducible control flow, unrolled tail calls, etc.

In a bytecode, most of this kind of optimisations have not been done (leaving them to the JIT), so it is much closer to an original source than it would have been with the metadata removed and optimisations applied. No matter, stack machine, register-based, threaded Forth code or whatever else.

Comment: I will note that my question discusses obfuscated C#, so identifier names are no longer an issue. What you say about lack of explicit (even if obfuscated name) data types is interesting - but I have to wonder if data types could also be inferred from assembly with proper tools. What you say about unrolled loops, tail calls and other optimizations also sounds interesting, and suggests natural next steps in obfuscator evolution.

Comment: @EndangeringSpecies, it might be possible to deconstruct some of the data types, but in most cases you would not even be able to match those types against each other (e.g., if you're only accessing a first field of a structure, there is no way to infer that it is the same structure as in a function accessing its second field only).

Comment: ok, so sounds like you are emphasizing the problem of resolving data types of structs in dynamically allocated memory because there is no explicit field access via instance reference. (So presumably we will find lots of papers about throwing static analysis at this problem but few free quality tools). This is interesting because this sounds like yet another possible future of the obfuscator, obfuscation via replacing objects with pseudo dynamic memory. Cool...

Answer (score 3):

In machine code that's meant for real hardware you don't always know where in memory the code starts. Since x86 instructions are of variable length, this can make a disassembler decode instructions with a wrong offset. Also the possibility of pointer arithmetic doesn't help. In .NET IL and java opcodes, it is always clear where code starts and ends, and arbitrary pointer arithmetic is not allowed. Therefore disassembly is 100% accurate, even if the generated assembly code is not easily legible. With real machine code, at least on the x86, you never know the exact control flow and code entry points unless you run the program, even if you assume that there is no code morphing going on.

Comment: can you clarify why variable length instructions are an issue? Isn't instruction tokenization obvious to the decompiler? If I can extract list of instructions and their addresses, wouldn't I be able to correctly resolve all the goto statements?

Comment: You are correct in that variable length is not exactly the issue here. The problem is that you can't reliably know the entry point to a block of code. But if instructions were of fixed length, I believe it would be easier to detect when your disassembly has began from an incorrect entry point because you'd more quickly see that some opcodes wouldn't make sense and you'd go back and try again with a different address. Variable length means opcodes are more compact, therefore there's less redundancy and less error detection. I think :)

Comment: what does "block of code" mean in easier to understand, high level language terms, i.e. what granularity are we talking about here? Is it methods? Or several lines without goto? Or multiple methods grouped based on some principle?

Answer (score 1):

For a comparison of C++ and Java from the ease of reverse engineering standpoint, read the intro section of [my article](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html). (You may read "C#" instead of "Java" and "CLR" instead of "JVM" :) )

As for calls to C standard libraries, if you link them statically, there will be no library function names in the binary. Furthermore, a C++ compiler will inline the small methods defined in the header files, not to mention what it will do with templates...